# Java: read in file and print

Tags: java, class, bufferedreader, filereader

I'm making a program that reads in a textfile with zoophobias. the name of the phobia and the name of the animal.

**The file looks like this:**

```
cynophobia          dogs

ailurophobia        cats

musophobia          rats

ichthyophobia       fish
```

**i want the output to look like this:**

```
ailurophobia - fear of cats

cynophobia - fear of dogs

ichthyophobia - fear of fish

musophobia - fear of rats
```

**this is the output i got:**

```
cynophobia - fear of  

ailurophobia - fear of 

musophobia - fear of

ichthyophobia - fear of
```

as you can see the name of the animal doesn't print...

My program consists off three classes, the main, Zoophobia and Dictionary.
The problem lies in the load() method and perhaps print().

//Main class

```
 package exercise1;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Dictionary dic = new Dictionary();
        dic.load();
        dic.print();

    }

}
```

//Zoophobia class

```
    package exercise1;

    public class Zoophobia implements Comparable<Zoophobia> {
        private String phobia, animal;

        //constructor
        public Zoophobia(String thePhobia, String theAnimal)
        {
            phobia = thePhobia;
            animal = theAnimal;
        }

        //INstance methods 
        public void setPhobia(String thePhobia)
        {
            phobia = thePhobia;
        }

        public void theAnimal(String theAnimal)
        {
            animal = theAnimal;
        }

        public String getPhobia()
        {return phobia;}

        public String getAnimal()
        {return animal;}

        //Fattar inte! //Slide 10
        public int compareTo(Zoophobia zp)
        {
            return phobia.compareTo(zp.phobia);
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            return phobia + " - fear of " + animal;
        }
    }
```

//Dictionary class

```
package exercise1;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Dictionary {
    private ArrayList<Zoophobia> arr;

    //Constructor that initializes the dynamic array
    public Dictionary()
    { arr = new ArrayList<Zoophobia>(); }

    //Method to read in data from file
    public void load()
    {
        String loaded, phobia, animal;
        String[] array;

        try{
        BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("old.txt"));

        while((loaded = infile.readLine()) != null)
        {
            array = loaded.split(" ");

            //Collections.sort(arr);
            arr.add(new Zoophobia(array[0].trim(), array[1].trim()));

        }

        infile.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ierr){}
    }

    public void print()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(arr.get(i)); 
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: For me, it works correctly. Both the phobia and animal field are correctly loaded in the Zoophobia object, and toString is ok...

Comment: It also works for me.  I would double check that your file does not contain any weird characters (like non-breaking spaces), and that you have properly compiled the latest version of all your files.

Comment: As a side note, `catch(IOException ierr){}` is horrible for debugging.  Do you really want it to silently fail if there's an IOException, without telling what the exception was?

Comment: hmmm interesting. I made a new identical file and it worked with the new file

Comment: catch(IOException ierr){} was recommended in my lecture slide. i don't really understand the statement fully to be honest

Comment: Just as a note, nowadays one should use the new I/O API of Java called **NIO**. It is more robust, has more to offer and is easier to read. Its main classes are `Files` and `Paths`. Therefore you can just use `Files.lines(Paths.get("old.txt"));`, it returns a `Stream<String>` on which you can iterate either using **Lambda expressions** or a regular `Iterator` by using the `Stream#iterator` method. This also solves the issue with the exception because **NIO** will not force you to do error handling.

Comment: As a small explanation to the **catch**, if the code inside the **try-block** encounters an exception then it will abort the code in the try-block. If you now have covered that exception with a **catch-block** you will enter this block of code in order to do proper **error handling**. However your error handling is just `{}`, which means "*do nothing*". So you just silently ignore the exception though the `FileReader` forces you to **handle the error case** since `IOException` is what is called a **checked exception** (you must catch it or also force your caller to do error handling).

Comment: To wrap it up, it seems that you have solved your problem. Do you know the error? If so, please answer the question by yourself so that the answer can help others with the same issue. If not you can decide to either delete the question or at least show us the file and leave the debugging to us.

Comment: thank you for all the food information, i appreciate it!!!
If you mean solving the original problem, there was something wrong withe the text file som i just maid a new one.